# Socket.io+SailsJS: Chat application-How to check whether the client is shut down,and make the user offline?

Tags: node.js, socket.io, sails.js, node-webkit

I am creating a multi-user chat application in node-web kit and SailJs and I was trying to implement login status of the users. User comes online when they open the application. The cases for the user to go offline are:

1. User clicks logout button
2. User closes the application window.
3. User turns his/her system off.

The logout status doesn't work when the user turns off their system. Here is a part of my code which I have written:

```
UserSocket.find({
  companyId: user.companyId
}, function (err, sockets) {
  if (!err && sockets != undefined && sockets.length > 0) {
    socketList = _.pluck(sockets, "socketId");
    sails.sockets.emit(socketList, 'userOffline', {
       previous: user
    });
  }
});
```

Please help me in figuring out this issue. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to use the onDisconnect method in the config/sockets.js ?

```
module.exports.sockets = {
    onDisconnect: function(session, socket) {
        //do your stuff here

    }
}
```

Comment: Yes I tried the same. But the user is is going offline only when he turns on his system again. At that time only the server gets to know that the socket is disconnected.